# Double integration of a function of e to y squared where one integral has a variable

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm not sure how to phrase the title, but I have a problem on my homework assignment that requires me to solve the following function.

$\int_0^2 \int_{x^2}^4 xe^{y^2} dy dx$

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20from%200%20to%202%20of%20integral%20from%20x%5E2%20to%204%20of%20x*e%5E%28y%5E2%29%20dy%20dx) gives a reasonable, seemingly correct answer, yet if I were to only ask it to integrate the inner integral, I get a function that includes the imaginary error function. This usually indicates that I'd have to use polar coordinates to solve it.

But, I've got no idea how to convert those boundaries to polar boundaries (I can't think of any clean way to do it - I would absolutely be able to if the boundaries were in $y = \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$ form.)

Nowhere in my textbook have I encountered such a problem, nor were there any in-class examples on how to solve one of these where a bound is a parabola instead of the form $y = \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$.

How would I go about calculating the polar bounds for a problem like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases, what often works is changing the order of integration and appropriately changing the limits as well. Here,

$$I=\int_0^2 \int_{x^2}^4 xe^{y^2} dy dx$$

The region is 
$$D=\{(x,y): 0\le x\le2, x^2\le y\le 4\}$$

This can be rearranged as,

$$D=\{(x,y):0\le y\le 4, 0\le x\le \sqrt{y}\}$$

The integral then becomes,

$$I=\int_0^4\int_0^\sqrt{y} xe^{y^2} dx dy=\int_0^4e^{y^2}\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_0^\sqrt{y}dy=\frac12\int_0^4ye^{y^2}dy$$

Now substitute $u=y^2$ and solve.

Comment: How did you rearrange the regions? I can see that you solved for x in y = x^2, and left the constant y = 4 limit. Is the reason you replaced x = 2 with x = sqrt(y) because at y = 4, x = sqrt(4) = 2?

Comment: @Josh In the original form, the lower bound for $y$ depends on $x$ so indirectly, the upper bound for $x$ depends on $y$. The lower bound of $x$ and the upper bound of $y$ are fixed, and remain the same. $x^2\le y$ implies $x\le \sqrt{y}$. $x\ge0$ and so $y$ also must be $\ge0$. It is much easier to see all this by drawing the graph of $y=x^2$ though.

Comment: So in a graphical sense, I would draw out the first region given, which would use vertical 'bars' for integration (to obtain the limits for y) along a constant-to-constant (in this case 0 to 4) x, then to convert, I would instead use horizontal 'bars' on a constant-to-constant y (which I would have to derive from this 'graph').

Comment: @Josh Yes, exactly.